# CKQueryOperation get the last record

Tags: iphone, xcode, icloud, cloudkit, ckquery

I need to fetch the very last record in cloudkit. Here is my code:

```
 CKContainer *container = [CKContainer containerWithIdentifier:containerID];
    CKDatabase *publicDatabase = [container publicCloudDatabase];
    CKQuery *query = [[CKQuery alloc] initWithRecordType:recordType
                                               predicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"TRUEPREDICATE"]];
     CKQueryOperation *queryOp = [[CKQueryOperation alloc] initWithQuery:query];

    queryOp.desiredKeys = @[@"record.recordID.recordName"];
    queryOp.recordFetchedBlock = ^(CKRecord *record)
    {
        //do something
    };

     queryOp.queryCompletionBlock = ^(CKQueryCursor *cursor, NSError *error)
    {
        NSLog(@"CKQueryCursor  error %@", error);
    };

    queryOp.resultsLimit = CKQueryOperationMaximumResults;
    [publicDatabase addOperation:queryOp];
```

My question is how can I modify my code to get the very last record in cloudkit?

I'll really appreciate your help

Answer (score 4):

You can sort on the creation dat ascending and then just ask for 1 result like this (code is in Swift):

Adding the sort:

```
query.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
```

Limiting the result:

```
queryOp.resultsLimit = 1
```

Comment: resultsLimit seems to have no effect for me

Answer (score 1):

Objective-C version

```
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:NO];
query.sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];
```

for one record:

```
queryOp.resultsLimit = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting resultsLimit does not seem to work for me, however set it anyway and  sorting the results using a timestamp or the record creation date.  Then store the results in an array and simply use the first or last item depending on the sort order

```
    CKContainer *container = [CKContainer containerWithIdentifier:containerID];
    CKDatabase *publicDatabase = [container publicCloudDatabase];
    CKQuery *query = [[CKQuery alloc] initWithRecordType:recordType predicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"TRUEPREDICATE"]];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:NO];
    query.sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];

    CKQueryOperation *queryOp = [[CKQueryOperation alloc] initWithQuery:query];
    queryOp.desiredKeys = @[@"record.recordID.recordName"];
    queryOp.recordFetchedBlock = ^(CKRecord *record)
    {
        //do something
        recordArray.append(record)
    };

    queryOp.queryCompletionBlock = ^(CKQueryCursor *cursor, NSError *error)
    {
        NSLog(@"CKQueryCursor  error %@", error);
        let myLastRecord = recordArray[recordArray.count - 1]
    };

    queryOp.resultsLimit = CKQueryOperationMaximumResults;
    [publicDatabase addOperation:queryOp];
```